# python: использование регулярного выражения для отрезания ограничительных скобок/кавычек

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, replace

У меня есть строка вида:

```
[ограничительный символ]текст[ограничительный символ]
```

например

```
(какой-то текст)
"ещё какой-то текст   "
```

Необходимо создать регулярное выражение, которое:

1. отрезает ограничительные символы, причём только парные, т.е. вариант `"текст)` трогаться не будет
2. у оставшегося текста отрезаются пробелы и табуляции по концам

Написал такую регулярку:

```
\([ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\)|\"[ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\"|\'[ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\'$
```

на сайте для тестов регулярок (https://regex101.com/) всё работает замечательно, но в питоне код:

```
re.sub(r"^\([ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\)|\"[ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\"|\\'[ \t]*(.*)[ \t]*\\'$", r"\1", text)
```

не работает

Подскажите в чем ошибка и как ее исправить о парности символов

P.S.

1. кстати исходное регулярное выражение почему-то не отрезает пробелы в конце строки - как это можно исправить?
2. можно ли как-то сократить размер регулярки при сохранении условия

Comment: При использовании `raw-string` не надо же бэкслэши экранировать. Так что или `r` убрать, либо экранирование.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, заметил эту ошибку, стало работать, но осталась старая проблема - не удаляются последние пробелы, и не срабатывают ограничители начала и конца строки `^...$` так что находится даже внутреняя начина, чего не хотелось бы

Comment: Наверное, для подшаблона `(.*)` нужно указать, что он `non-greedy`. Иначе и пробелы конечные именно туда попадут, а не в `[ \t]*`. Так что попробуйте все захватывающие шаблоны заменить на `(.*?)`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, помогло, СПАСИБО. Осталась одна проблема - алгоритм почему-то не реагирует на начало и конец строк и ищет внутри строки, чего не хотелось бы или в питоне какие-то другие символы начала и концы строки чем `^$`?

Comment: Хм, я даже проверил, вроде такого не наблюдаю. Проиллюстрируйте примером. Кстати, похоже тут все группы нумеруются, а не только одна и нужно заменять на `r"\1\2\3"`

Comment: Символы начала и конца строки будут работать с параметром `m` `re.MULTILINE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как ответы на основной вопрос были даны в комментарии, то предложу немного другой вариант регулярного выражения:

```
regex = r"^(?:(\()|([\"']))[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*(?(2)\2|\))$"
```

Преимущество данного выражения в том, что данные всегда будут находиться в **третьей** `\3` группе захвата.

Пример: [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TQb4H7/1)

---

О логике:
`(?:(\()|([\"']))` - используем незахватываемую группу, для поиска ограничивающего символа с **логическим или** - или открывающуюся скобку `(` или одна из кавычек одинарная и двойная `"'`
`[ \t]*` - ноль и более табуляций и знаков пробела
`(.*?)` - группа в которую попадут под захват нужные данные (3я группа)
`[ \t]*` - ноль и более табуляций и знаков пробела
`(?(2)\2|\))` - проверка, если вторая группа была захвачено, значит первым символом в строке была захвачена кавычка (одинарная или двойная), если это так, то ищем до аналогичного символа, иначе закрывающаяся скобка `)`

Comment: Посмотрел рейтинги комментатора и автора вопроса и думаю: "куда я лезу". Поэтому если мой ответ кого-то заденет или оскорбит, то просто удалите его, спасибо)

Comment: Да ладно, я вообще регулярки слабовато знаю, хотя и начинал программировать когда-то давно именно с регулярок в языке `Perl` )  Да и как ещё рейтинг набирать - только давая ответы. Хороший ответ, всё расписано.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, это наверное офтоп, но на мете бывает вижу, где новичков обвиняют в копировании ответов из комментариев