# Python: удаление первого и последнего символов в строке (при некоторых условиях)

Tags: python, строки

стоит задача:

есть строка, если строка заключена в кавычки или в круглые скобки, то удалить их, затем убрать пробельные символы (даже если ничего удалять не требовалось)

код такой:

```
def mystrip(text):
    return (text[1:-1] if text[0] == text[-1] and text[0] in '\'"' or text[0] == '(' and text[-1] == ')' else text).strip()
```

Вопрос чисто эстетический - а как можно эту задачу сделать красиво (т.е. понятный, но при этом и короткий код)? Через регулярки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1411539/python-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba

Comment: блин, совсем забыл :)))

Answer (score 2):

Вариант покороче исходного без `regexp`:

```
texts = ['"(12345)"', '( ..... )', '   6789 ', ' "879)', '"     aaaa"']
drop = {'()', '""', '**', '##'}  # итд
for t in texts:
    out = (t[1:-1] if t[0] + t[-1] in drop else t).strip()
    print(out)
```

```
(12345)
.....
6789
"879)
aaaa
```

Comment: `(test'` - будут удалены `(` и `'` , т.е. некорректно

Comment: мне кажется хороший вариант получился в итоге, но наверно если преобразовать в функцию мой код будет покороче

Answer (score 0):

Короче можно, но насколько понятнее зависит уже от знания регулярок, в данном случае используется `|` - как разделитель вариантов для `match`:

- `^".*"$` двойные кавычки
- `^\(.*\)$` скобки (должны быть экранированы)
- `^'.*'$` одинарные кавычки (тоже экранируем или внешние делаем `'''`)

код (переносы чтобы избежать скрола):

```
import re
def mystrip(text):
  return (text[1:-1] if re.match(r'^".*"$|^\(.*\)$|^\'.*\'$', text) else text)
    .strip()
```